# Adding a Style Sheet

Tags: magento2.3, css

I am trying to add a Style sheet in my Magento 2 store. My **default_head_blocks.xml** is like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"  src_type="url" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
        <css rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" src_type="url" /> 
        <css src="css/fixed_css.css"/>
        <css src="css/custom.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

**fixed_css.css** code is like below

```
.search-hearder-main.row {
    justify-content: center !important;
}
/* Facebook */
.fa-facebook {
background: #3B5998;
color: white;
}
/* Twitter */
.fa-twitter {
background: #55ACEE;
color: white;
}
.fa {
padding: 20px;
font-size: 30px;
width: 30px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

I ran **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** command.
But I am getting only below code when I am inspecting using **ctrl + u** .

```
.search-hearder-main.row {
justify-content: center !important;
}
```

I tried in several ways. I ran below commands.

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush**

I flushed all the caches here.

[image]

Now I placed below CSS in **fixed_css.css** file.

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

But nothing is working.

Comment: Run rm -rf pub/static/* then run content deploy command

Comment: Thanks @Pawan, I did all these, result is as like before.

Answer (score 1):

To add css or js use vendor_module::style.css
Refer this link for more info http://this-adarsh.epizy.com/module-development-3/

Happy Magento

Comment: Thanks @Adarsh Shukla. How to know which `vendor_module` I have ? Thanks.

Comment: Where your head default file is located?

Comment: Thanks. Here is the location `public_html/app/design/frontend/Codazon/fastest/grocery_gourmet/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

Comment: Try Magento_Theme and reed from above link for more info

Comment: Thanks @Adarsh Shukla. I am getting this error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/olUXa.png

Answer (score 1):

create **default.xml** in `app/code/yourvendor/yourmodulename/view/frontend/layout`

add this below lines of code in it:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   layout="admin-1column"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"
>
   <head>
       <css src="Yourvendorname_Yourmodulename::yourstylesheet.css"/>
   </head>
   <body/>
</page>
```

**now put your css at below location**

```
app/code/Yourvendorname/Yourmodulename/view/frontend/web/css
```

Now go to root and room content from Pub/static/frontend
now run the magento commands of `setup:upgrade` and `deploy` `flush cache`

now check your changes on frontend
**hope this helps**

Comment: Thanks @Chikku. How to know `Module` name ?

Comment: can you share your code of module.xml file

Comment: Thanks @Chikku. What is the location of `moduel.xml` file ?

Comment: <magento root>app/code/yourvendorname/yourmodulename/etc/module.xml

Comment: follow this link on how to create a basic custom module in magento 2

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/

Comment: Thanks @Chikku. How to know What is my `Module` name ? I found these directories inside `app/code/Codazon` this direcotry.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn1cv.png.

I couldn't find my `Module` Name.